# Safari not always rendering page

Tags: php, apache, safari

Having an issue where Safari will not always render the page. When it does, it doesn't always show all the images. Issue happens with all the sites run off one set of code. One site is http://www.wfar.com/.

I check the Apache access log and can see the hit, and it passes back a 200 and roughly 8,000 in data. Nothing shows in the error log.

Look in the developer tools, and Safari shows that it received a 304. Nothing is set in my code to return a 304, so must be coming from apache.

I can recreate the issue on multiple computers and iPhones.

Comment: The `304` is fine, it means "not modified". http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html So you are definitely getting a blank, white page? What does the "view source" view say in that case?

Comment: The view source is completely empty.

Comment: @John strange. Can you exclude the possibility of a PHP fatal error? Because that's the only thing that comes to mind that could cause an empty response without an error code from the server. Do you log  PHP errors?

Comment: I can refresh the website all day in any browser including Chrome, but can't recreate the problem. I'll try logging my errors, or something to see if the request makes it that far.

Comment: I put my speculations into an answer. Maybe one of them helps.

Comment: Nothing shows in the error log, and doesn't trigger my test code.

Disabling cache, javascript, styles, site-specific hacks, run-away javascript timer doesn't fix the issue.

My co-worker has found this https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26621 (that I now know he found from your answer). Sounds like my issue, without all the redirects.

Comment: @John yeah, I found that one too, you should be able to find out whether it applies by trying it with Safari 3.x. If the problem doesn't occur there, it's that bug. One last idea: Gzip encoding is often the root of such problems. If you have control over your web server, you may want to try turning it off altogether for a short span and try out whether the problem persists.

Comment: I'll delete my answer, unanswered questions tend to attract more attention.

Comment: First thing I checked was gzip. Have it turned off from previous problems with IE.

Comment: Really strange! I'm out of ideas. Will be interested to see what this turned out to be, be sure to leave a comment here. Good luck! Unrelated: You are aware that your IE style sheet is in between the `head` and the `body` tag?

Comment: I wasn't, but our designer now is.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Apache logs report a 201 Created, ONLY Safari reports 304 Not Modified and a totally blank page. All PHP error reporting levels are on. Works in all other browsers. I am at my wit's end on this issue, and don't know what to do. Did you ever resolve this and get it working consistently with Safari?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is related with a 304 BUG.

http://tech.vg.no/2013/10/02/ios7-bug-shows-white-page-when-getting-304-not-modified-from-server/

The only workaround I found was to send a STATUS 200 for MobileSafari and Safari. (iOS 7.0.2 and Safari 7 on OSX)

Answer (score 0):

I got this problems with JavaScript. Change the code of one file results in an empty page. So here is an uncomfortable workaround :

1. Change the script code

   - Load the page (it will be blank)
2. Comment out the script(s) from the html-file
3. Reload the page (it will be rendered)
4. Remove the comments in the html file (so the script(s) will be loaded again)
5. Reload the page (it will be rendered correctly with the changed script code)

I know, very nasty, but I think user3297914 is right and this way you get around the STATUS 304...

Comment: I can't test this to know if this worked for the above situation. I was told by a co-worker that after I left, they fixed it by upgrading something on the server. Something to do with PHP.